# How to delete multiple Kubernetes pods having the same name expression except the latest one?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have multiple pods running as below. I want to delete them all except the one having minimum age. How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? Perhaps also add `-l app=value` to filter for a specific app

```
kubectl get pods --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp -o name | head -n -1 | xargs echo kubectl delete
```

(Remove `echo` to do it for realz)

Comment: there are other pods also, other than samplepod-XXX. I don't want to delete them. How we are taking care of pod prefix samplepod- ???

Comment: You can either insert `grep "^pod/samplepod-"` (before `head ...`. Or better yet, look at the labels of the samplepods with `kubectl get pod --show-labels` , there is probably something like `app=sample`, then you can just filter by changing the get part: `kubectl get pod -l app=sample` (as I hinted in the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use PowerShell and pipe the output to the Foreach-Object, which then loops over each line:

```
kubectl get pods -n default -o name | ForEach-Object { kubectl delete $_ }
```